# Remove copyright symbol

Tags: text-processing, sed, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse a RSS feed on the command line. The code works so far but the feed contains a copyright symbol which I try to remove (it is latin1 encoded). How do I remove the copyright symbol (`\xA9`) using maybe `sed`?

Comment: Have you tried `sed 's/\xA9//g'`?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, surprisingly it didn't work.

Comment: By the way, 17 USC 506(D) makes it a Federal crime to remove or alter a notice of copyright from a copy of a copyrighted work if your intent is fraudulent. (If your intent is just to make something work, you should be okay.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the only problem, I agree with @Kevin; if the entire feed is non-UTF-8, I'd maybe look at `tr -cd SET` to delete all characters not in SET, or `iconv -f (encoding) -t utf-8` if you know the encoding of the feed.

Comment: Please see the warning about tr in a comment to *Ladadadada's* answer... (ref [Wikipedia tr (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29).. look for *'not Unicode compliant'*...

Comment: Yes and no. `tr` is safe if you want to delete down to ASCII or a subset thereof: the 8th bit is set if and only if one is looking at a multi-byte representation.

Answer (score 2):

`tr -d '©'` works to simply remove it.

If you want to replace it with a string, you can use

`sed 's/©/(c)/g'`

Comment: Warning!.. `tr` works at the byte level, not per character. This mean that `tr -d '©'` will do different things depending on which locale `tr` is run in. Eg. the typical 'nix locale of UTF-8 means that `©` resolves to 2 bytes *'\xC2'* and *'\xA9'* .. `tr` will delete all occurrences of **either** byte... This will remove the the *'\C2'* from `§` and the *'\A9'* from `é`, and from any of the many other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for adding that fered. I had no idea `tr` worked that way.